# Delete all rows except the ones with a specific value

Tags: excel, vba

How, based on column values, can I keep certain rows and delete the rest?

Right now I repeat the values I want to delete.

```vb
With ActiveSheet
    FirstRow = 4
    LastRow = 10000

    For Row = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
        If .Range("A" & Row).Value = "ITT1" Then
            .Range("A" & Row).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next Row
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to negate your `If` statement using `<>` or `Not`:

Just use

```
If .Range("A" & Row).Value <> "ITT1" Then
```

or

```
If Not .Range("A" & Row).Value = "ITT1" Then
```

to delete all rows except the ones with `ITT1` as value in column A.

---

Note that instead of hard coding the last row `LastRow = 10000` you can determine it using something like:

```
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  ' get last used row in column A
```

So if you only have `100` rows the loop does not start at `10000` but just loops over the rows that actually have data.

---

So It should look something like:

```
With ActiveSheet
    Const FirstRow As Long = 4

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  ' get last used row in column A

    Dim Row As Long
    For Row = LastRow To FirstRow Step - 1
        If Not .Range("A" & Row).Value = "ITT1" Then
            .Range("A" & Row).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next Row
End With
```

If it has to delete a lot of rows this might get a bit slow. So I recommend to collect the rows to delete in a variable using `Union` and delete them all at once in the end, which is **much** faster:

```
With ActiveSheet
    Const FirstRow As Long = 4

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  ' get last used row in column A

    Dim RowsToDelete As Range  ' here we collect which rows to delete

    Dim Row As Long
    For Row = LastRow To FirstRow Step - 1
        If Not .Range("A" & Row).Value = "ITT1" Then
            If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                ' set first row
                Set RowsToDelete = .Range("A" & Row).EntireRow
            Else
                ' add all the other rows
                Set RowsToDelete = Application.Union(RowsToDelete, .Range("A" & Row).EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next Row

    If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        RowsToDelete.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "No rows to delete were found."
    End If
End With
```

If you collect all rows to delete in a variable first you even don't need to run the loop backwards `Step - 1` and just use a normal forward loop if you like:

```
For Row = FirstRow To LastRow
```

Comment: Fantastic, really great help!!